# Multiple series with subplots for shared columns in DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have two DataFrames with identical row indexes and column names that are sometimes only in one DataFrame, and sometimes in both. I wanted to plot data from columns that are in both DataFrames and arrange them in subplots. The final figure should look like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| ColumnA1 + ColumnB1 | ColumnA2 + ColumnB2 |
| ColumnA3 + ColumnB3 | ColumnA4 + ColumnB4 |

For now I tried to simply have the plots done, without arranging them in subplots. But if any of the columns is not present in both DataFrames, none of the plots are showing:

```
for column_name in [DataFrameA.columns, DataFrameB.columns]:
        DataFrameA[column_name].plot(label = "A")
        DataFrameB[column_name].plot(label = "B")
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Save the column names for each DataFrame as sets `a` and `b`. After that, create a new set `c` that contains only the elements which are contained in BOTH sets (the intersection of the sets). Next, use a for loop to iterate over each column name in `c` and plot the data. This is just like the code in the question, except iterating over the new set `c` instead of `[DataFrameA.columns, DataFrameB.columns]`.

#### Code

```
a = set(list(DataFrameA))
b = set(list(DataFrameB))
c = a.intersection(b)

for column_name in c:
        DataFrameA[column_name].plot(label = "A")
        DataFrameB[column_name].plot(label = "B")
        plt.show()
```